# What are the database tables related to comments in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, comments, entities

I received a lot of spam comments in one of my websites running on Drupal 7. I googled for a solution to delete them in bulk and came up on

```
DELETE FROM comment WERE status = 0
```

The query worked but the database size did not shrink significantly and I realized out that in addition to the 'comment' table there was another table called

```
 field_data_comment_body
```

which housed the body of the comment.

I would like to know which all tables are related to comments in Drupal 7

Comment: Comments are entities, and the body is a field. Deleting comments directly from the comment table is a very, very bad idea, you should use the API functions (e.g. [`comment_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_delete/7))

Comment: Yup it was a really bad idea. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Any idea how to get out of this mess?

Comment: Restoring your latest db backup would be the first step, then you can write a script to delete the comments 'properly'. If you're struggling with that script just ask another question here, someone will be able to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these on your PhpMyAdmin:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE comment;
TRUNCATE TABLE field_data_comment_body;
UPDATE node_comment_statistics SET comment_count = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE field_revision_comment_body;
```

**Take care: all the comments will be deleted!**

Comment: Yea this seems to be a good solution too for deleting all the comments. However it is not feasible if you want to preserve a few comments.

Comment: I think ```TRUNCATE TABLE comments``` will be ```TRUNCATE TABLE comment```

Comment: -1: `TRUNCATE TABLE comment` will delete every comment, not just unapproved spam comments

Answer (score 2):

I know following tables.
1. comment
2. field_data_comment_body
3. field_revision_comment_body
4. node_comment_statistics

Beside that, I think, comments are also stored in any other tables installed by modules, and linked to comment modules.

Answer (score 0):

So, the question is which tables are related to comments in Drupal 7? Not which SQL commands to run ;-)

If you haven't added any fields to the comment entity (for any content type), the correct tables has already been mentioned:

- comment
- field_data_comment_body
- field_revision_comment_body
- node_comment_statistics

For each field you add to the comment entity you get two more tables.

Example: For a content type "blog", you have added an email field to the comment. In other words you find a field with machine name "field_comment_email" (or similar) on admin/structure/types/manage/blog/comment/fields. Then you have two more tables:

- field_data_field_comment_email
- field_revision_field_comment_email

This quickly gets messy. To repeat what @Clive said ;-)

> Deleting comments directly from the comment table is a very, very bad idea, you should use the API functions.